# How can I UPDATE 2 table columns in SQL Server with 1 query?

Tags: sql-server

```
UPDATE Subscription.dbo.RefillSubscriptionHeader AS H
INNER JOIN Subscription.dbo.RefillSubscriptionDetail AS D 
ON D.reSubHeaderId = H.reSubHeaderId 
SET H.isActive2 = '0', D.isActive = '0'
WHERE reItemID = '56'
```

In the above query I am trying to join 2 tables and update the `IsActive` and `IsActive2` columns.

Right now when I do a SQL syntax check I get

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

If I cannot update 2 columns from 2 tables the best bet would be to update the H table.

Comment: an `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` can only affect *one* table. Whilst there are forms that allow other tables to be used for filtering or locating values of interest in other tables, it doesn't change this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an UPDATE statement will only hit one table, your best bet would then be

```
UPDATE H
 SET H.isActive2 = '0'
FROM Subscription.dbo.RefillSubscriptionHeader AS H
INNER JOIN Subscription.dbo.RefillSubscriptionDetail AS D 
ON D.reSubHeaderId = H.reSubHeaderId 
WHERE reItemID = '56'
```

Of course, you can put both updates in one `TRANSACTION`, and if you provide the right [TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) you can still ensure the "atomicity" of the operation

Answer (score 0):

An update statement can only update one table/view.  Nice try though!